# Initializing a variable causing printf to stop working

Tags: c

```
int get_max_horizantal()
{
    char str[2];
    char strb[2]; //Everything works well unless I put this
    extern char shit[1200];
    int x,number;
    while((3*x+1)<1200)
    {
        if(number%17==0 && number!=0)
        {
            x+=2;
            number=-1;
        }
        str[0]=shit[3*x];
        str[1]=shit[3*x+1];
        int val1=atoi(str);
        printf("%d\n",val1);
        x++;
        number++;
    }
}
```

Ok so this is something I don't get at all...The whole function works well but when I put this
char strb[2];
printf doesn't print anything and there are no compile errors or warnings...
This time I really need help on this one...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't name your variable `shit`

Comment: `x` and `number` are used uninitialized.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `atoi` on a char array, you must put a null terminator at the end.
Adding things to the stack changing the behaviour often means you have walked off the end of some memory.
Make str bigger and add the null at the end:

```
char str[3];
str[2] = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :D
It'll take me long to get used to C hehe :D

Comment: Thanks but this still doesn't work...
Still the same

Answer (score 3):

`atoi` wants a proper string. What you pass it is not a proper string since it's not nul-terminated. This leads to undefined behavior which in your case presents itself as seemingly unrelated change making things work or not work.

Comment: I see...Thanks a lot..I think it'll take me a very long time to actually learn using C well..Still thanks :D

Comment: You'll need a lot more time and some reading to learn C. Be patient and work and read a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The [atoi(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html) function expects a null-terminated string, that is an array of `char` containing a zero byte (which conventionally terminates the string).

You should give at least 3 characters to `str` and zero them before filling them, either using `memset` or explicitly clearing the last byte:

```
char str[3];
/* possible alternative:
   memset (str, 0, sizeof(str)); // the compiler will optimize that...
*/
str[0] = shit[3*x];
str[1] = shit[3*x+1];
str[2] = (char)0;
```

Please take the habit of **enabling all warnings and debugging information** at compile time (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux), and **learn how to use the debugger** (`gdb` on Linux).

I'm sure that your compiler is able to warn you that `x` and `number` are not initialized, and you should fix that:

```
int x=0, number=0;
```

As a rule of thumb, improve your source code till no warnings are given by your compiler (with all warnings requested by e.g. `-Wall` and possibly even also `-Wextra` if using `gcc`). Then use a debugger to debug your code: on Linux the `p` or `print`, `s` or `step`, `d` or `display`, `bt` or `backtrace` commands of `gdb` should become familiar to you.

---

Consider using [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) (but don't use the deprecated and unsafe `sprintf`).

---

Learn about [**Undefined Behavior**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Your program might apparently happens to work (by lack of luck) but be buggy.

Comment: Thanks but this still doesn't work...
Still the same

Comment: It's still not printing anything when I initialize str2 
I am not getting this at all

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger and to step by step your program. Debugging skills (including familiarity with a debugger like `gdb`) are mandatory when coding, specially in C or C++....

Comment: Aha..
I just tried compiling here
http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php
And it works pretty fine but doesn't on CodeBlocks..But I'll consider your advice..Thanks :D

Comment: CodeBlock is an IDE (that is a glorified editor). You could use some other editor (like `emacs`). But you need to use a compiler, and you should enable all warnings on your compiler, and you need to use a debugger. Don't expect stackoverflow to debug your crappy code (especially, naming a variable `shit` does not invite us to debug a shitty code ...)